# XPath with dittoed fields?

Tags: xpath

In this document if the second column is blank it means use the previous row's value.

```
<doc>
<table>
<tr><td>ASU</td><td>CS</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>ASU</td><td>English</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>ASU</td><td></td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>ASU</td><td>French</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td>CMU</td><td>CS</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>CMU</td><td>English</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>CMU</td><td>French</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>CMU</td><td></td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td>SDSU</td><td>English</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>SDSU</td><td></td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>SDSU</td><td></td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>SDSU</td><td>French</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
</doc>
```

I want rows were the second columns are `English` so these would be the rows:

```
<tr><td>ASU</td><td>English</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>ASU</td><td></td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>CMU</td><td>English</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>SDSU</td><td>English</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>SDSU</td><td></td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>SDSU</td><td></td><td>5</td></tr>
```

What would the XPath be for this?

Answer (score 2):

(This is using XPath 1.0, there may be better solutions with more recent XPath versions).

First, you want `tr`s, so that’s straightforward:

```
/doc/table/tr[...some predicate...]
```

The rows you want are either:

1. Those with where the second `tr` just contains “English”

   ```
   tr[2] = 'English'
   ```
2. Or those where the second `tr` is empty...

   ```
   tr[2] = ''
   ```

   and, looking at the previous sibling rows which don’t have an empty second `tr`...

   ```
   preceding-sibling::tr[td[2] != '']
   ```

   the first one (`[1]`) has a second `tr` that contains “English”

   ```
   /td[2] = 'English'
   ```

So combining all that, a query that gives you the desired rows is:

```
/doc/table/tr[td[2] = 'English'
  or (td[2] = ''
    and preceding-sibling::tr[td[2] != ''][1]/td[2] = 'English')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment about my answer. I'll delete it.